# Spring: как загрузить таблицу из DB в память?

Tags: java, spring, config

Здравствуйте,
у меня есть небольшая таблица, которую я хочу загрузить в память в виде `List<Country>`, чтобы не дергать БД. Но... как это правильно сделать?

DataSource такой:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Value("${jdbc.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public Sql2o sql2o() {
        return new Sql2o(dataSource());
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чём проблема? Объявляете бин в конструкторе которого выгребаете данные из базы в поле-коллекцию и все последующие обращения к данным делаете через методы этого бина.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я это делаю обычно таким образом:

Создаю бин-holder с коллецией/мапом объектов, в методе `@PostConstruct` выгружаю из БД необходимые данные ну и реализую необходимые `get` методы.

Псевдоjavaкод:

```
@Component
public class CountryHolder {
    @Inject/@Autowired
    private Dao/DataSource dao/dataSource;

    private Map<String, Country> countries; //ключ, нампример, название страны

    @PostConstruct
    private void initCountries(){
        //Выгружаем из нужной таблицы данные, инициализируем countries
    }        

    /*
    ...
    ...//необходимые методы для работы
    ...
    */

}
```

далее в коде можете инжектить этот бин и использовать по назначению

```
@Inject
private CountryHolder countryHolder;

...
...
countryHolder.getCountries();
...
...
```